# Help managing many-to-one results for lookup

Tags: sql, db2, toad, many-to-one

I didn't see this exactly asked, so I'm hoping it wasn't.

I have a table that has multiple columns with code variables and a table that has all lookup codes and descriptions for the whole database. Is there a way to join the lookup values so that everything stays on one row, instead of what i'm getting where one row has the race value and one row has the sex value. Thanks. I'm using TOAD but understand SQL.

```
Table 1                      
User_id    Race_cd  Sex_cd              
101          3201     4501              
102          3201     4502              
103          3202     4501               
104          3203     4501 


Table 2
CD_Num      CD_descrip
3201        White
3202        Black
3203        Asian
4501        Male
4502        Female
```

Comment: I think you'll need a pivot query of some kind to "rotate" the rows into columns. The exact syntax tends to be DBMS-specific, so you'll need to tell us which DBMS are you using?

Comment: it's a ODBC DB2 database. I've worked with similar systems before but not run into the issue of having one translation/lookup table, so it's just new to me. thanks for your help

Comment: i figured out i can just join to the lookup table multiple times, but there must be a less roundabout way to pull each coded value onto the same row.

Comment: @ChrisFisher - No, you're going to have to `join` multiple times - and it's usually better, to make it more explicit what you're doing.  I'd recommend following @Louis's example and create views - although use some sort of `group` descriptor instead of `id` ranges (add a column if necessary, but it shouldn't be part of the view).

Answer (score 1):

I played around for an hour with the joins over your tables, without an easy result.

Then I created views like this :

```
create view race as select * from lookup where id < 4000

create view sex as select * from lookup where id > 4000
```

thenafter, the select was just this easy :

```
select user.id, race.desc, sex.desc  from users, race, sex 
       where user.ra = race.id 
       and user.se = sex.id
```

showing up this :

```
101    White    Male
102    White    Female
103    Black    Male
104    Asian    Male
```

May this inspire you a nice solution ! ( You will naturally have to deal with the "between value and value" predicate when creating your views. )

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for something other than multiple joins, which is what this is performing.  I agree with using views to segregate the data, although I'd prefer using some sort of `group` descriptor, not a range of `id`s for this purpose.